# Automapper, Entity framework update database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper

I'm using Auto mapper and Entity framework, this is great saves me a lot of coding, but when doing a update I have an issue.

I use the following to attach an entity to the EF context and then use auto mapper to update the elements, this is fine if the value is not updating to the default value (IE string to null, int to 0 ect..)

```
var entity = new Car
{
    CarId = carViewModel.CarId,
};

db.Cars.Attach(entity);

AutoMapper.Mapper.Map(carViewModel, entity);

db.SaveChanges();
```

Does auto mapper have any features that could help with this or do I need to manually set some overriding defaults?

The other option to to load the existing item from the database and update that but I would like to avoid this as I shouldn't need to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is actually that Entity Framework doesn't know your entity has been changed.  Instead of using `db.Cars.Attach`, try setting the entity state:

```
var entity = new Car();
AutoMapper.Mapper.Map(carViewModel, entity);
db.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified; 
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: that's interesting, when debugging the code using the attach the State was set as modified, but only scripted changes for properties that has updates that where different to the base null possition, by setting the State as described it now updates all filed's which is exactly what I want in this case, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can change the state of your entity to modified:

```
db.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

[See this MSDN article for more info on entitiy states](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj592676(v=vs.113).aspx)